# Exception raised during rendering: -1 when adding ToggleButton

Tags: android-layout

When adding (manually or drag/drop) ToggleButton to layout, I got this message:

```
Exception raised during rendering: -1
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error LogThe graphics preview in the layout editor may not be accurate:
Different corner sizes are not supported in Path.addRoundRect. (Ignore for this session)
Path.isConvex is not supported. (Ignore for this session)
```

Every other button work fine.Talking about Eclipse.

e:Seems like API 21 does not work with togglebutton when API5 works. Is should not be like that, right?

Comment: Here is a issue added regarding this problem : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to the "graphical layout" of your whatever.xml file  and locate the drop down menu heading various device names e.g it may nexus 4 etc. select your android virtual device from the list i.e name of your AVD.then again try to  add "toggle button" and see.
in my case it worked , i have no idea why.